# Core Animation - Play 2 Animations in Sequence

Tags: ios, animation

I'm trying to put together an animation that works a little like a speedometer.

The first animation gets the needle

```
CFTimeInterval localMediaTime = [needle convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];

CABasicAnimation *needAni = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
needAni.duration = 0.5f;
needAni.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
needAni.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(rotVal * M_PI / 180.0)];
needAni.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.195: 0.600: 0.790: 0.405];
needAni.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;

[needle.layer addAnimation:needAni forKey:nil];
```

After that plays I would like to have the needle bounce back and forth a little when its reached full speed. This animation does just that:

```
CABasicAnimation *needAni2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
needAni2.duration = 0.1f;
needAni2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(rotVal * M_PI / 180.0)];
needAni2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((rotVal+5) * M_PI / 180.0)];
needAni2.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
needAni2.autoreverses = YES;
needAni2.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
needAni2.beginTime = localMediaTime + 0.5f;

[needle.layer addAnimation:needAni2 forKey:nil];
```

Now when I put this together only the second animation plays.

I tired putting these two animations into a group, but I can't seem to just repeat the second animation, it repeats the whole process. Is there a performance problem if I put the group duration equal to HUGE_VAL or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just stick with your method, as this seems to be the intended usage of CAGroupAnimation. Just make sure you set an appropriate duration for the group. If you make the duration for the group shorter than your intended animations, it will cut your animations short. If you make the duration longer than your animations, the animation objects might possibly linger in memory until that duration is over.

Another option would be to implement the delegate method -animationDidStop:finished: , and add the  second animation when that gets called by the first animation.

CAAnimation reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation

Comment: Thought about that as well. I've been reading that it's kind of bad form to do this. That have any truth to it?

Comment: Well, it should work fine in this case, but it is a bit icky.. If nothing else, it's not a method that would scale well to more complicated animations